# JavaScript.. Use values of local variables in other functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables

I've been searching for days to solve this problem...

[image]

[image]

As shown in the image above,
I need to apply the data values from other places to the Vuetify Primary
I've been googling over and over again, but I can't find the answer...
Can you tell me the answer?

This is the JavaScript in question

```
const primaryColor = variablecolor

export function setColor(variablecolor) {
  console.log('colorCheck',variablecolor)
}

export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: primaryColor,
          secondary: '#5CBBF6',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

These are the methods that are sent to the JavaScript in question

```
  methods: {
      updateColor() {
        setColor(this.btn_color)
      },
    }
```

Comment: No, you absolutely cannot use local variables outside of the function. But that's not really want you want anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically update the initial theme object used by `createVuetify` but you can instead have your `updateColor()` method directly modify `$vuetify.theme` where the theme colors are made accessible as noted in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing)

> values will also be made available on the instance $vuetify object under the theme property. This allows you to dynamically modify your theme. Behind the scenes, Vuetify will regenerate and update your theme classes, seamlessly updating your application.
>
> // Light theme
>
> this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = '#4caf50'
>
> // Dark theme
>
> this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary = '#4caf50'

In your case, the method would look something like this:

```js
updateColor() {
  this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = this.btn_color
}
```